# Is there a way to fix the navigation tab position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm facing a problem with relative position and the bottom borders of a navigation tab. That could be seen in this GIF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbGL7.jpg

I just want that the "Option X" (and another options that come later) fixed at the left bottom position.

```
/* Code moved to jsfiddle */
```

**UPDATE**: I could simulate it in the https://jsfiddle.net/g9qs869r/2/

Comment: please add the html into your question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with you styles. You are making top row element height bigger then rest of the elements. In order to eliminate difference you can add to all tabs:

```
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #FFF; // added border in order to keep element height
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g9qs869r/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a specific height to the li attribute, if you put this line on your css the behavior changes as you need

```
.nav-tabs > li{ height:40px;}
```